# Why is the function unique?

Tags: real-analysis

Let a certain function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that $f(nm) = f(n) f(m)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(f(n))}{\log n} = 1$.

**Answer :**

Evaluation on $m^n$, gives $$1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log (f(m^n))}{\log(m^n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n\log(f(m))}{n\log(m)}=\frac{\log(f(m))}{\log(m)}$$ So $m=f(m)$.

**Comment :**

Someone told me that there are no other choices for $f$, $f$ has to be the identity function, since :

1. I am using the fact that if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $b$, then any subsequence $a_{n_k}$ converges to $b$. In my calculation, I fixed a $m$ and let that subsequence be $k \mapsto m^k$.
2. Thus, my only work for $m\neq 1$. Indeed, $k \mapsto 1^k$ does not give me a subsequence. But of course in this case it is even easier to verify that $f(1) = 1$ using $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$.

I don't understand the link between the uniqueness of $f$ and his comment. Is anyone is able to explain to me?

Comment: I can't follow your question. You've shown $\log f(m)=\log m$. So $f(m)=m$ when $m>1$. As you say, $f(1)=1$ can be proved. That pretty much shows uniqueness.

Comment: What does it _mean_ to say that $f$ is unique? It means that there is only one $f$ satisfying the given conditions. Starting from those conditions you've shown that $f(m)=m$. So you've shown that $f$ is unique - you've shown that the conditions imply $f(m)=m$, so you've shown that that's the only function satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments lead to a proof that $f(m)=m$ for all $m$:
By induction on $k$ you find from the given functional equation that $f(m^k)=f(m)^k$ for all $m\in\Bbb N$, $k\in\Bbb N$.

For $m>1$, the sequence $m, m^2,m^3,\ldots$ is a subsequence of $1,2,3,\ldots$, hence 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log f(m^k)}{\log (m^k)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log f(n)}{\log n}$$
But also 
$$ \frac{\log f(m^k)}{\log (m^k)}=\frac{\log(f(m)^k)}{\log(m^k)}=\frac{k\log f(m)}{k\log m}=\frac{\log f(m)}{\log m},$$
which does not depend on $k$, hence $\frac{\log f(m)}{\log m}=1$ and so $f(m)=m$.

For $m=1$, the above cannot be applied (both because $1,1^2,1^3,\ldots$ is constant instead of a subsequence and because we must not divide by $\log 1=0$). But we get immediately that $f(2)=f(1\cdot 2)=f(1)f(2)$ and hence from $f(2)=2\ne 0$ (by the preceding result), $f(1)=\frac{f(2)}{f(2)}=1$.